# Why create another SQLiteDataReader instead of re using one?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqlite

I search on 2 tables, one field on each table

```
Using conn As New SQLiteConnection(SQLiteConnStr)
    Try
        conn.Open()
            Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM NamesTable"
            Dim cmd As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)

            Dim reader As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Try
                    While (reader.Read())
                        ComboBox.Items.Add(reader("Name"))
                    End While
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString())
                End Try

            Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM CityTable"
            Dim reader2 As SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Try
                    While (reader2.Read())
                        ComboBox.Items.Add(reader2("City"))
                    End While
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString())
                End Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try

End Using
```

**Is because I search on 2 different tables that I need to create another SQLiteDataReader  and can´t just reuse the first one?**

Comment: You got two good answers, please consider accepting one so this gets moved off the Unanswered List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what a query is: an instruction to read some data from a specific table.  The `DbCommand` and `DbDataReader` used to do that are specific to that task - there's very little that is reusable about them.

You can't actually create a `DbDataReader` - it is created for you by the `DbCommand` object (there is no public constructor). It is very specific to the query being run, there is no way to restart it with a new SQL command.

That said you can shorten your code by not repeating yourself:

```vb
Private Function BuildDataTableForMe(sql As String) As DataTable
    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection(SQLiteConnStr)
        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)

            conn.Open()
            Dim dt As New DataTable()

            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
            Return dt
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Usage:

```vb
' dont use SELECT * if you dont need everything
cboCity.DataSource = BuildDataTableForMe("SELECT Id, City FROM CityTable")
' ??
cboCity.DisplayMember = "City"
cboCity.ValueMember = "Id"
cboName.DataSource = BuildDataTableForMe("SELECT Id, Name FROM NamesTable")
'??
cboName.DisplayMember = "Name"
cboName.ValueMember = "Id"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I read that it was not appropriate for the Try block - Catch call a procedure or external function. Ie keeping the code within the Try. Now I see that you can call a function, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You're not creating a new command, so the `cmd` variable still refers to the original command.

You need a new line of `cmd = New SQLiteCommand(sql, conn)` so that you get a brand new command.

And you're not reusing the reader or the command - it's a new command and a new reader, just happen to have the same variable names as the original ones, but they're brand new objects.

Comment: "And you're not reusing the reader or the command" Right, that was the question, if I try to use on the second search the same SQLiteDataReader objetc ( reader on this case ) I get a error. If I understand your answer, with the same SQLiteCommand I can´t use the same SQLiteDataReader  more than once?